# How to calculate results from built_in metrics

Tags: k6

I am creating monitoring system (k6+grafana+influxdb) with docker.

I want to use built-in metrics (not http-specific) to calculate e.g. data_received per request/group or full iteration in worst case, but all I get in influxDB in `data_received` database are some timestamps with `data_received` values, however I don't see a way to generate useful info from it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain why you are getting only timestamps, maybe a problem with how you look at your data? There is a way to make [tags into fields](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/blob/master/release%20notes/v0.21.0.md#influxdb-output-add-support-for-sending-certain-sample-tags-as-fields-585) which is not that well documented but even with it you should still have some tags attached to all metrics.

But you can attach more:

For http requests (including data_received metric from those)  you can add tags with the `k6/http`'s method using [params](https://docs.k6.io/docs/params-k6http). It is important to note that for the [http.get](https://docs.k6.io/docs/get-url-body-params), there is no body argument, so the `params` are the second, not the third, argument as with the others.
If you are using websockets, see [their documentation](https://docs.k6.io/docs/k6-websocket-api).

I suppose you can use a [custom metric](https://docs.k6.io/docs/result-metrics#section-custom-metrics) and are add some values if the built-in are not enough. If you take a look at the [k6/metrics](https://docs.k6.io/docs/k6metrics) documentation and more specifically the example you will see that each and every time you [add](https://docs.k6.io/docs/gauge-add-value-tags) a data point you can add a tag **for that datapoint**, not the **whole** metric.

Additionally you can [output to json](https://docs.k6.io/docs/results-output#section-json-output) with `--out json` or `--out json=file.json` and than use jq as shown, again [in the documentation](https://docs.k6.io/docs/results-output#section-processing-json-output).